# How to insert data in SQLite and display it using RecyclerView

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-recyclerview

i made RecyclerView to display data from Mysql and it work good now i want to make a favourite button when i clicked on it save this item in a favourite and display it in new activity in RecyclerView

I think i should use Sqlite to save data in it then display in favourite activity but i don't know how i can make that please help me

I tried to make Sqlite

```
public class DB_Sqlit extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String BDname = "mdata.db";

public DB_Sqlit(Context context) {
    super(context, BDname, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table favorite ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, img TEXT, url TEXT, num TEXT, size TEXT)");
        }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS favorite");
    onCreate(db);

}



public Boolean Insert_to_favorite(String name, String img, String url, String num, String size) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("img", img);
    contentValues.put("url", url);
    contentValues.put("num", num);
    contentValues.put("size", size);


    long result = db.insert("favorite", null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}


public ArrayList getAllList_Favorite() {
    ArrayList<listitem_gib> arraylist = new ArrayList<listitem_gib>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor rs = db.rawQuery("select * from favorite", null);
    rs.moveToFirst();
    while (!rs.isAfterLast()) {
        String id = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("id"));
        String name = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("name"));
        String img = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("img"));
        String url = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("url"));
        String num = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("num"));
        String size = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("size"));


        arraylist.add(new listitem_gib());
        rs.moveToNext();
    }
    return arraylist;
}

public int get_check_List_Favorite(String Title) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor rs = db.rawQuery("select * from favorite Where name like '"+ Title +"'", null);
    rs.moveToFirst();
    int count = rs.getCount();
    return count;
}


public Integer Delete(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("favorite", "id = ?", new String[]{id});
}}
```

### RecyclerView Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_r_arabic);

    GetDataAdapter1 = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);

    progress_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progress_layout);
    progress_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL();

}

public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL(){

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    story_type = intent.getStringExtra("story_type");


    String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = "http://grassyhat.com/android/" + story_type + ".php";

    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL,

            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    progress_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

        listitem_gib GetDataAdapter2 = new listitem_gib();

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            GetDataAdapter2.setId(json.getString(id));

            GetDataAdapter2.setName(json.getString(name));

            GetDataAdapter2.seturl(json.getString(url));

            GetDataAdapter2.setimg(json.getString(img));

            GetDataAdapter2.setnum(json.getString(num));

            GetDataAdapter2.setsize(json.getString(size));

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
    }

    recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, this);


    //RecyclerView needs a layout manager in order to display data so here we create one
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    //Here we set the layout manager and the adapter to the listview
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);

}
```

### RecyclerViewAdapter

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;

List<listitem_gib> getDataAdapter;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<listitem_gib> getDataAdapter, Context context){

    super();

    this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_layout, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v,context,getDataAdapter);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    listitem_gib getDataAdapter1 =  getDataAdapter.get(position);

    holder.name.setText(getDataAdapter1.getName());

    holder.num.setText(getDataAdapter1.getnum());


    Picasso.with(context).load("http://grassyhat.com/android/image/" + getDataAdapter1.getimg()).into(holder.img1);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return getDataAdapter.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener{


    public TextView name;
    public TextView num;
    public ImageView img1;

    Context context;
    List<listitem_gib> getDataAdapter;



    public ViewHolder(View itemView, Context context ,List<listitem_gib> getDataAdapter ) {

        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
        this.context = context;

        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Main_Text) ;
        num = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Second_Text) ;
        img1 = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img1) ;


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        listitem_gib getDataAdapter =this.getDataAdapter.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.context,Rewaya_info.class);
        intent.putExtra("name",getDataAdapter.getName());
        intent.putExtra("url",getDataAdapter.geturl());
        intent.putExtra("img",getDataAdapter.getimg());
        intent.putExtra("num",getDataAdapter.getnum());
        intent.putExtra("size",getDataAdapter.getsize());
        this.context.startActivity(intent);

    }
}}
```

### ListItem

```
public class listitem_gib {

String id;
String name;
String url;
String img;
String num;
String size;


public String getName() {

    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {

    this.name = name;
}

public String getid() {

    return id;
}

public void setId(String id1) {

    this.id = id1;
}


public String geturl() {

    return url;
}

public void seturl(String url1) {

    this.url = url1;
}

public String getimg() {

    return img;
}

public void setimg(String img1) {

    this.img = img1;
}

public String getnum() {

    return num;
}

public void setnum(String num1) {

    this.num = num1;
}
public String getsize() {

    return size;
}

public void setsize(String size1) {

    this.size = size1;
}}
```

Comment: do you have any error with this code? BTW, be careful with "onUpgrade", you are dropping the table which means that once you update the database version all your users will lose their favorites.

Comment: i don't know how i can make that i just see a tutorial and made Sqlite but i don't know how i can use it and make a favourite activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you need to use SQLite database to store fav items data offline

   - create one table containing all data fields by make a class extends SQLiteOpenHelper and override onCreate() to write your create table command in it, and you don't need to write anything in onUpdate() method in your case
   - in your Detail activity make a button for fav which will implement insert this item in the SQLite database

     ---
2. to view the data from SQLite in RecyclerView:

   - make an arraylist from your item type "class"
   - retrieve each item data from SQLite database using cursor
   - add item data in the arraylist and send it to the adapter of the RecyclerView

     ---

you can use this tutorial to build RecyclerView :
[Arabic Version](http://www.hendiware.com/%D8%AA%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%80-recyclerview-%D9%88%D9%85%D8%A7-%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%80-adapter/)

or [English Version](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)